# Novel where a group of video-game-playing friends are told that the game was real. They enter the game together

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this book a few years ago and I want to reread it.

A group of friends plays a video game together. They do a massive feat in the game and then are told that the game is based off reality and they have been selected to fight in this war. One of the friends is accepted while everyone else is turned away.

Not wanting to be split up they enter the realm and go rescue the friend who was accepted officially.

The book was an MMORPG style in English. It was aimed towards older teen-adult audiences. It is a series.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: You've said that this is all you can remember, but I doubt that's true. For example, what language did you read the book in? Was it aimed at adults (with explicit sex/violence/gore) or younger readers? What did the cover look like? What was the name of the game they were playing? What style of game was it (RPG, FPS, Starfighter, etc)? What were the names of the friends? Were they male or female? What was the name of the main character? Why was he selected and not the others? Who selected them? How were they transported? Was it into the game or *elsewhere*. Who were they fighting?

Comment: Lots of similar tropes here; https://www.amazon.co.uk/Neverfall-Mark-Hero-Book-Gamelit/dp/1728621089. Lotsa suggestions here; https://www.reddit.com/r/litrpg/comments/vd9k3b/what_are_some_vr_litrpgs_that_become_real/

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this would be the book as it's aimed at a partially younger audience, and only has 1 book in the series, but is it Gamer Army by Trent Reedy? Or perhaps a similar type of series?

It has about 5 main characters, one of which is a boy named Rogan who is the focus. They're playing games but find 'glitches' in the battles they're facing, and soon realise that they've been fighting real-life battles through futuristic sci-fi gaming.

It doesn't completely match the question as it has aspects missing, but this is the first book I could link to the description.